# Animating frame Images with ease effect on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, easing, rotator

Let me show you example (360 Deg 3D Object Rotator): 
Demo: http://activeden.net/item/interactive-renders-360-deg-3d-object-rotator/39718?ref=mixDesign
[image]
As you see, there is a camera 3D rotating on mouse event. Actually, it is a collection of images (frames) animating frame by frame depending on mouse event.
I want to implement this animation with **objective - c** using **swipe gesture** (or maybe I should use another gesture?). So that I can make rotation by my finger, to the **left**, to the **right** (I want animation with smooth ease effect, depending on swipe **speed velocity**).
 
***Note:*** I have ready images for each frame.

Sample codes, online tutorials doing this will really help me.
**! Should I use some external graphics library, in order to keep performance? I have hundreds of images (PNG), each with size of 300kb**
Thank you in advance, I really need your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should use swipe gesture here. I recommend you LongPressGesture with short minimumPressDuration.

Let me show example code:

```
longPress = [ [UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)] 
longPress.delegate = self;
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.05;
[viewWithImage addGestureRecognizer:longPress];


float startX; 
float displacement = 0;
-(IBAction)handleLongPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{   

float nowX;
    if ( sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ) 
    {
        startX = [sender locationInView:viewWithImage].x;
    }
    if ( sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
       ... do something at end ... 
    }
nowX = [sender locationInView:mainWidgetView].x;
displacement = nowX - startX; 

  // set right rotation with displacement value
  [self rotateImageWith:displacement];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it will be easier to go with `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:`, and `touchesEnded:` here? This will allow you to react to velocity and direction changes very fast.

Update: example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767404/iphone-slide-movement-recognizer).